# How can I improve sorting in Postgres 16?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have the query below which takes about 2 seconds to execute if sorting is not done, and about 40+ seconds if sorting is done.

Is there a way to improve the sorting timing to bring it in a single digit range?

I've already increased the work_mem from 4GB to 40GB but haven't seen any improvements in the timing.

My DB instance is : PostgreSQL 16.0 (Debian 16.0-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit

DB files are stored on a 2 TB nvme gen 3.

The DB container is running on a dual CPU Xeon 2630 V2 with 64GB of RAM.

At this moment, there are about 160 million records in the search table, but only about 3 million matching the locale = 'en'.
The products_locations table has about 15 million records in total.

Note that these numbers will only go up.

Query:

```sql
SELECT ppl.id, ppl.location_id, 
  calculate_distance(ppl.latitude, ppl.longitude, 45.4754304,
    -73.4756864, 'K') AS distance 
FROM search sh
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT p.id, p.category, p.rating, p.health_score, p.efficiency_score, 
    p.eco_score, pl.id AS location_id, pl.base_price, pl.price_100,
    pl.quantity, pl.latitude, pl.longitude, pl.currency, pl.aisle,
    pl.store_id, pl.is_online 
  FROM products p 
  LEFT JOIN products_locations pl ON pl.product_id = p.id 
    AND ((pl.latitude <= 45.5204 AND pl.latitude >= 45.43047
     AND pl.longitude <= -73.41156 AND pl.longitude >= -73.53981) 
    OR covered_regions ILIKE '%=CA-QC=%') 
) ppl ON sh.product_id = ppl.id 
WHERE 1 = 1 AND ppl.category IN ( 1 ) AND sh.text &@* 'salt' 
  AND sh.locale = 'en' 
ORDER BY distance ASC NULLS LAST 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Note that the distance has to be calculated for each query. It cannot be calculated in advance as it depends on some input coordinates.

Query explain analyze verbose output:

```
Limit  (cost=5865583.61..5865583.63 rows=10 width=40) (actual time=41015.372..41015.381 rows=10 loops=1)
  Output: p.id, pl.id, (calculate_distance((pl.latitude)::double precision, (pl.longitude)::double precision, '45.4754304'::double precision, '-73.4756864'::double precision, 'K'::character varying))
  ->  Sort  (cost=5865583.61..5865592.51 rows=3561 width=40) (actual time=40634.188..40634.196 rows=10 loops=1)
        Output: p.id, pl.id, (calculate_distance((pl.latitude)::double precision, (pl.longitude)::double precision, '45.4754304'::double precision, '-73.4756864'::double precision, 'K'::character varying))
        Sort Key: (calculate_distance((pl.latitude)::double precision, (pl.longitude)::double precision, '45.4754304'::double precision, '-73.4756864'::double precision, 'K'::character varying))
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=285685.60..5865506.66 rows=3561 width=40) (actual time=3736.395..39893.634 rows=2019651 loops=1)
              Output: p.id, pl.id, calculate_distance((pl.latitude)::double precision, (pl.longitude)::double precision, '45.4754304'::double precision, '-73.4756864'::double precision, 'K'::character varying)
              Hash Cond: (p.id = pl.product_id)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..5555191.45 rows=3561 width=16) (actual time=2077.389..29232.771 rows=2012603 loops=1)
                    Output: p.id
                    Inner Unique: true
                    ->  Index Scan using search_product_id_lang_text_idx on public.search sh  (cost=0.00..5527417.00 rows=3561 width=16) (actual time=2077.276..17470.331 rows=2014112 loops=1)
                          Output: sh.id, sh.product_id, sh.locale, sh.text, sh.username, sh.creation_time, sh.update_time
                          Index Cond: (((sh.locale)::text = 'en'::text) AND (sh.text &@* 'salt'::text))
                    ->  Index Scan using products_id_idx on public.products p  (cost=0.43..7.80 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=2014112)
                          Output: p.id
                          Index Cond: (p.id = sh.product_id)
                          Filter: (p.category = 1)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 0
              ->  Hash  (cost=284349.47..284349.47 rows=106856 width=48) (actual time=1658.568..1658.572 rows=181222 loops=1)
                    Output: pl.id, pl.latitude, pl.longitude, pl.product_id
                    Buckets: 262144 (originally 131072)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 16560kB
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.products_locations pl  (cost=48272.92..284349.47 rows=106856 width=48) (actual time=662.642..1583.833 rows=181222 loops=1)
                          Output: pl.id, pl.latitude, pl.longitude, pl.product_id
                          Recheck Cond: (((pl.longitude <= '-73.41156'::numeric) AND (pl.longitude >= '-73.53981'::numeric) AND (pl.latitude <= 45.5204) AND (pl.latitude >= 45.43047)) OR (pl.covered_regions ~~* '%=CA-QC=%'::text))
                          Heap Blocks: exact=119626
                          ->  BitmapOr  (cost=48272.92..48272.92 rows=132641 width=0) (actual time=630.308..630.311 rows=0 loops=1)
                                ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=48246.21..48246.21 rows=53446 width=0) (actual time=527.770..527.772 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_locations_longitude_idx  (cost=0.00..15542.24 rows=606968 width=0) (actual time=159.704..159.705 rows=585171 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: ((pl.longitude <= '-73.41156'::numeric) AND (pl.longitude >= '-73.53981'::numeric))
                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_locations_latitude_idx  (cost=0.00..32650.29 rows=1275773 width=0) (actual time=357.549..357.549 rows=1290797 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: ((pl.latitude <= 45.5204) AND (pl.latitude >= 45.43047))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on product_location_covered_regions_idx  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=79194 width=0) (actual time=102.535..102.535 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (pl.covered_regions ~~* '%=CA-QC=%'::text)
Planning Time: 16.027 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 22
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 4.399 ms, Inlining 48.738 ms, Optimization 213.331 ms, Emission 119.286 ms, Total 385.754 ms
Execution Time: 41115.276 ms
```

Comment: Without sorting, all it needs to do is find the 10 easiest to find rows, and then stop.  For a true comparison, show a plan for the query omitting both the ORDER BY and the LIMIT.

Comment: First things first. That's not a LEFT JOIN but an INNER JOIN. The predicate `ppl.category IN ( 1 )` defeats the outer join and silently converts it into an inner join. Do you want an inner join or an outer join?

Comment: What is the `&@*` operator?

Comment: Most time is spent on the indexes search_product_id_lang_text_idx and products_id_idx. The statistics for both are way of, like excepting to find `rows=3561` but in reality `rows=2014112`. Use ANALYZE or even create custom statistics

Comment: @jjanes &@* operator performs similar search in pgroonga.

Comment: @TheImpaler ppl.category IN ( 1 ) is actually a filter coming from the application. It may or may not be set, depending on user query. In this example it just happen to be set.

Comment: @Yonoss Then, the filter needs to be placed in the `ON` clause, not in the `WHERE` clause. As it is, the query does not make too much sense.

Comment: you might want to look at Postgis and the `<->` [distance operator](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) which makes use of a spatial index when used in the `order by` clause

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing too much about what you've already addressed or looked into, here's a handful of ideas that may or may not be worthwhile:

1. If your `calculate_distance` function is similar to the one shown here (https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/postgresql), alter it to be `STRICT`, `IMMUTABLE`, and `PARALLEL SAFE`.
2. Consider changing the structure of your query to examine the `search` table last.
3. Convert your latitudes & longitudes to the `earth` type from the `earthdistance` extension, and add a GiST index on them.

For a bit more detail on each of these:

1. `STRICT` is a shorthand for `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT`, meaning that PostgreSQL need not execute the function if any argument is null, which may be a significant number of rows. `IMMUTABLE` indicates that the function is a "pure" function, neither reading from nor writing to the database, and always returning the same result for the same input. `PARALLEL SAFE` indicates that the function may safely be executed by multiple workers simultaneously. Each of these will affect the query planner's understanding of the function, and could potentially result in some significant savings. See here (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) for more.
2. Its possible that PostgreSQL is spending quite a bit of time executing the text similarity comparison on products that would be excluded by your latitude/longitude box clause. I hesitate to mention this, because you say that your "unsorted" query is an order of magnitude faster, but the explain plan definitely seems to indicate that the index scan on `search_product_id_lang_text_idx` is the most expensive step. Experiment with something like this:

   ```sql
   SELECT p.id, pl.id as location_id, 
     calculate_distance(pl.latitude, pl.longitude, 45.4754304, -73.4756864, 'K') AS distance 
   FROM products p 
     JOIN search sh on sh.product_id = p.id
     JOIN (
       SELECT id, product_id, latitude, longitude
       FROM products_locations 
       WHERE covered_regions ILIKE '%=CA-QC=%'
         OR (pl.latitude <= 45.5204 AND pl.latitude >= 45.43047
          AND pl.longitude <= -73.41156 AND pl.longitude >= -73.53981) 
     ) pl on pl.product_id = p.id
   WHERE p.category IN ( 1 ) 
     AND sh.text &@* 'salt' 
     AND sh.locale = 'en' 
   ORDER BY distance ASC NULLS LAST 
   LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
   ```

   (Note that this hinges on making each `LEFT JOIN` into a regular (inner) `JOIN`. If its important that "locationless" products be included, you may have to do a bit of trial and error to get it to work correctly, or potentially use two separate queries.)
3. This item centers on the idea of adding a GiST index capable of filtering and/or ordering based on distance directly. It involves adding the `earthdistance` and `cube` extensions, and converting all of your latitude & longitude columns to the `earth` type. A back-of-the-napkin migration script might look like:

   ```sql
   -- CREATE EXTENSION cube;
   -- CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance;

   ALTER TABLE products_locations ADD COLUMN location earth;
   CREATE INDEX products_locations_location_idx ON products_locations USING gist (location);
   UPDATE TABLE products_locations SET location = ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude);
   ALTER TABLE products_locations DROP COLUMN latitude, DROP COLUMN longitude;
   -- ALTER TABLE products_locations ALTER COLUMN location SET NOT NULL;
   ```

   And the updated query might look like:

   ```sql
   SELECT ppl.id, ppl.location_id,
     -- the distance between two locations, accounting for the curvature of the earth, in meters
     earth_distance(ppl.location, ll_to_earth(45.4754304, -73.4756864)) as distance,
     -- the straight-line distance between two locations, in meters
     ppl.location <-> ll_to_earth(45.4754304, -73.4756864) as straight_distance
   FROM search sh 
   LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT p.id, p.category, p.rating, p.health_score, p.efficiency_score, 
       p.eco_score, pl.id AS location_id, pl.base_price, pl.price_100,
       pl.quantity, pl.location, pl.currency, pl.aisle, pl.store_id, pl.is_online 
     FROM products p 
     LEFT JOIN products_locations pl ON pl.product_id = p.id 
       -- locations within a 300 Km cube centered on the coordinates
       AND (earth_box(ll_to_earth(45.4754304, -73.4756864), 300000) @> location
       OR covered_regions ILIKE '%=CA-QC=%') 
   ) ppl ON sh.product_id = ppl.id 
   WHERE 1 = 1 AND ppl.category IN ( 1 ) AND sh.text &@* 'salt' 
     AND sh.locale = 'en' 
   -- using `straight_distance` to take advantage of index on `<->` operator;
   -- order should be equivalent to using `distance`, without the "sort" step
   ORDER BY straight_distance ASC NULLS LAST 
   LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
   ```

   For reference, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/earthdistance.html, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/cube.html, and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/indexes-types.html#INDEXES-TYPE-GIST.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestions @tboz203 ! I will give them a try and will let you know how it went. And yes the calculate_distance  function is the one you mentioned.  As for using gist indexes on location objects instead I had the feeling that it will be faster to use btree indexes on numeric columns. Anyhow I will give it a try and see what I can squeeze out of this query

Comment: I've played around with the suggestions you mentioned, but the only thing that helped were the changes on calculate_distance function. That shaved out about 10 seconds.

Comment: Using gist indexes and sorting on straight_distance tends to be slightly slower than my original approach. The change of the join and/or their orders, yields results in similar time interval.